# Facebook Like Button Breaks Other Social Widgets and Anchors

Tags: jquery, facebook, asynchronous

I have a Facebook like button/widget, twitter widget, Google+ widget and an anchor tag on the same page.

If the Facebook like button is removed everything works.

If the Facebook like button is displayed then the like button works but all other widgets including a simple anchor tag do not.

Is there any reason why this should not work?

Facebook SDK is loaded via jquery asynchronously

```
$('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
$.getScript('http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js')
.done(function(script, textStatus) {

    // Initialize Facebook javascript SDK.
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : settings.appId,
            channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        initSocialWidgets();
        initFacebookPlugins();
    };
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
});
```

Widget html is insert dynamically using jquery.

```
// Facebook.
script = '<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>';
$('#facebook-widget-container').append(script);

// Twitter.
script = '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-via="ezoetic">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>';
$('#twitter-widget-container').append(script);

// Google.
script = '<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div><script type="text/javascript"> (function() { var po = document.createElement(\'script\'); po.type = \'text/javascript\'; po.async = true; po.src = \'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js\'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);  })();</script>';
$('#google-widget-container').append(script);
```

Comment: Have you checked for JS errors in the console? If you test it on Chrome, press Ctrl+Shift+I and click on Console. Post any errors you find.

Comment: Try to initSocialWidgets() before $.getScript() // FYI http://techcrunch.com/2012/02/03/facebook-javascript-api-goes-down-taking-down-likes-comments-and-apps-with-it/

Comment: There are no console errors and moving the initSocialWidgets() function did not make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem here is the data-width="450" attribute in the fb-like div.

A Facebook like button width of 450px was overlaying all other widgets/anchors in the row.  So all other widgets/anchors would show but could not be clicked.

However, setting the data-width to 108px (the measured width of the Like+Send button) did not fix the problem either.  It still resulted in a Facebook like button width of 150px.  Setting the data-width to less than 108px had no effect either.

The final solution was to simply add a css to the Facebook like button container.

```
.product-view #facebook-widget-container {
    width: 108px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only want to run `FB.init()` inside of the `window.fbAsyncInit`  callback, otherwise it's not certain that the FB has been properly setup by the js code.

This may be throwing an error stopping the javascript parser in the client's browser, and therefor not running `initSocialWidgets();`

Put a simple `console.log(1);` before the call to FB.init(), then a console.log(2) right after it, and see if both logs end up in the console.

Comment: Agreed that FB.init() should be wrapped inside the window.fbAsyncInit function.  This didn't fix this specific issue but suspect it would cause problems in the future.  Have updated the question code to reflect this.

Comment: Solved!  The core problem here is the data-width="450" attribute in the fb-like div.  450px width overlays other controls.  Don't have enough points to post an answer straight away but will post more details later.